# can't bind form group with component angular 6

Tags: angular

this is a simple form group with angular6:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from '../../commun/model/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-newcontact',
  templateUrl: './newcontact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newcontact.component.css']
})
export class NewcontactComponent implements OnInit {

  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: ''
    });
}

onSubmitForm() {
  const formValue = this.userForm.value;
  const newUser = new User(
    formValue['firstName'],
    formValue['lastName'],
    formValue['email']
  );

}
```

```html
   <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
    </form>
```

this is my model user:

```js
export class User {
  constructor(
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string,
    public email: string
  ) {}
}
```

I have a error, firebug said can't bind form group , what I forget in my snippet ?
With visual sudio , i not have error.

thank's for reply

Comment: your form should be: <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">firstName:<input formControlName="firstName"  placeholder="Enter firstName">
  lastName: <input formControlName="lastName"  placeholder="Enter lastName"> Email: <input formControlName="email"  placeholder="Enter email">
    </form>

Comment: I add input , but i have à same erreur:Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
  firstName:
  <input formControlName="firstNam"): ng:///AppModule/NewcontactComponent.html@0:6

Comment: I found it,I not export  ReactiveFormsModule,